# Decimal Places in Availability SLO's

Tags: google-cloud-platform, availability

In GCP, is it possible to set up an Service Level Objective(SLO) for a product or service using more than one decimal place - eg 99.99% or 99.999%

The maximum I seem to be able to do is 99.9%.

The most I can do is 99.9%.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE Enterprise Autopilot Pods in Multiple Regions, you can reach 99.99%

Firestore multi-region can reach 99.999%